# How to set a search engine in Firefox to redirect to an extension

Tags: firefox-addon, search-engine

I am developing a search engine extension for Firefox and I want to set it as (default) search engine using JavaScript. That means, if
somebody wants s/he should be able to type some query into the search field or the address field and the search should be redirected to the
extension. This is pretty easy to do when the target URL is a real address like `http://mysearch.com` (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963256/adding-a-custom-search-engine-to-firefox) and [the relevant Mozilla Developer documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Add-ons/Creating_OpenSearch_plugins_for_Firefox)), but it does not work if you try it with an extension URL
like `resource://my-search-extension/search.html`. Is there some way to still achieve this, e.g. by some hook listening on query inputs in
the search or address field?

P.D. You can set up a bookmark shortcut so that you can redirect a search like `s keyword` to an extension, but this not a convenient option
in my case.